# Trying to query multiple documents from Firestore in React at once, using an array from the users profile

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

This is my current code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    profile.familyCode.forEach((code) => {
      console.log(code._id)
      onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "group-posts", code._id, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      ),
      (querySnapshot) => {
        const posts = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setMessages([...messages, posts])        
      }
      )
    })
```

There are TWO code._id's and currently it is only setting my messages from one of them. What am I missing here?

Ive tried using some of firestores logical expressions to do the same thing with no success. This way I can at least pull some of them, but I would like to pull ALL of the posts from BOTH code._id's

Comment: Sorry, fixed the last found bug i did in my code. If you have any issues with my code - please, tell me so i can fix it up for you and future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the fact that `setMessages` is not updating `messages` itself immediately. So `messages` are closure-captured here with the old (or initial value) and calling `setMessages` will just overwrite what was previously set by previous `onSnapshot`.

Next issue - `onSnapshot` returns the `unsubscribe` function which should be called to stop the listener. Or you will get some bugs and memory leaks.

Here is a fast-written (and not really tested) example of possible solution, custom `hook`.

```
export function useProfileFamilyGroupPosts(profile) {
  const [codeIds, setCodeIds] = useState([]);
  const [messagesMap, setMessagesMap] = useState(new Map());

  const messages = useMemo(() => {
    if (!messagesMap || messagesMap.size === 0) return [];
    // Note: might need some tweaks/fixes. Apply .flatMap if needed.
    return Array.from(messagesMap).map(([k, v]) => v);
  }, [messagesMap])

  // extract codeIds only, some kind of optimization
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!profile?.familyCode) {
      setCodeIds([]);
      return;
    }
    const codes = profile.familyCode.map(x => x._id);
    setCodeIds(curr => {
      // primitive arrays comparison, replace if needed.
      // if curr is same as codes array - return curr to prevent any future dependent useEffects executions
      return curr.sort().toString() === codes.sort().toString() ? curr : codes;
    })
  }, [profile])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!codeIds || codeIds.length === 0) {
      setMessagesMap(new Map());
      return;
    }
    const queries = codeIds.map(x => query(collection(db, "group-posts", x, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")));
    const unsubscribeFns = queries.map(x => {
      return onSnapshot(x, (querySnapshot) => {
        const posts = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        // update and re-set the Map object.
        setMessagesMap(curr => {
          curr.set(x, posts);
          return new Map(curr)
        })
      });
    });

    // we need to unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks, etc
    return () => {
      unsubscribeFns.forEach(x => x());
      // not sure if really needed
      setMessagesMap(new Map());
    }
  }, [codeIds]);

  return messages;
}
```

The idea is to have a `Map` (or just `{}` key-value object) to store data from snapshot listeners and then to flat that `key-value` to the resulting `messages` array. And to return those messages from hook.

Usage will be

```
const messages = useProfileFamilyGroupPosts(profile);
```